argument needs to be of type (SquadExample, dict), while trying to build a RAG
Getting this error for QA using the below code, how can I create a SquadExample? I went to the docs and there weren't any information on how SquadExample dict must be created. Can someone help?
    prompt_template = """
    As a US Census information assistant, answer the question given the context.

    question: {question}

    context: {context}
    """

    QA_CHAIN_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=prompt_template, input_variables=["question", "context"]) 

   question =  """What were the trends in median household income across different states in the United    States between 2021 and 2022."""

    from langchain.chains import create_retrieval_chain
    from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain
    from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate

    system_prompt = (
               """As a US Census information assistant answer the question {question}."""
               "Context: {context}"
           )
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", system_prompt),
        ("human", "{question}"),
    ]
)

question_answer_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, QA_CHAIN_PROMPT)
chain = create_retrieval_chain(vectorstore.as_retriever(), question_answer_chain)
   
result = chain.invoke({"input": question, "question": question})


I tried going to the docs and looked for information on how to create a SquadExample using (create_sample) but I'm not sure on how to implement the same. A little assistance would be of great help!

Update:
I have two things 1. SquadExample object and 2. {"input": question, "question": question} (dict)
Now how do i invoke the llm to answer my question?

HuggingFace Pipeline Only supports text-generation, text2text-generation, summarization and translation for now.
Here is an example. Refer to the below code to integrate langchain with huggingface llms.
model_id="mistralai/Mistral-7B-Instruct-v0.3"
model=AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_id)
tokenizer=AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=["question", "context"],
    template="""
    You are an intelligent agent. Answer the questions based on the given context.
    Context: {context}
    Question: {question}

    Answer:"""
)
print(prompt_template)
pipe=pipeline("text-generation",
              model=model,
              tokenizer=tokenizer,
              max_new_tokens=100
              )
llm=HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)
llm_chain = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt_template,
    verbose=True
)
question = "What is the name of the repository?"
context = "The name of the repository is huggingface/transformers"
llm_chain.invoke({"question": question, "context": context})


Thank you for your response!
Understood, but I do have a question. How can question-answering be supported? Like if I'm considering to try and incorporate it? contributing to open-source, in a sense. If it can be done, how should my approach be?
Sorry if this is a stupid question.

You mean you want to contribute to add the functionality of question-answering in the huggingface pipeline. You can contribute in repo

Yes, how do I go about doing that? I haven't contributed to open-source before? Are there any guidelines as such? Just understanding how it functions and then tweaking right?

Yes, please refer to the langchain contribution section in readme.https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#-contributing
